# Nano Memory card does not show up in Finder nor Disk Utility

Tags: disk-utility, mojave, external-disk

I have a Nano Memory card working fine. I know it's fine because it contains a bootable ubuntu OS that is being used in a Raspberry Pi.

When I plug it to my Macbook Pro (Mojave 10.14.5) it does not show up in Finder nor even in Disk Utility.

Comment: With the card in the MacBook and Disk utility open, go to `View > Show All Devices.` Does that change anything?

Comment: What do you mean by a "Nano Memory card"? Do you mean a MicroSD card? If so, how are you plugging it into your computer?

Comment: It already set to see all devices. @duskwuff you have Micro SD and a smaller version called nano. And yes, I have it plugged.

Comment: Can you include a picture of this device, and of how you have it connected to your computer?

Comment: I have it connect using this adapter: https://satechi.net/products/satechi-aluminum-type-c-micro-sd-card-reader

Answer (score 1):

Working as designed.  macOS doesn't support the linux filesystems that linux uses to boot.  The one I use for booting is ext4.

check what filesystem you formatted flash driver with.

For ext4, you can install one of these drivers.

http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/20/mount-ext-linux-file-system-mac/

https://www.paragon-software.com/us/home/extfs-mac/#

Comment: I installed the paragon trial and it doesn't mount the sd. I have a new sd card and it was working ok. Then I installed Raspbian and from that point, Disk Utility and paragon stop seeing it. Raspbian is working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you need to take the drive back to linux and find out what filesystem you used to format the drive.   df -T ; https://askubuntu.com/questions/309047/how-do-i-find-out-what-filesystem-my-partitions-are-using